# Trac will not resync with SVN repository

Tags: python, svn, windows-7, trac, bitnami

After a bit of fighting, and switching to [Bitnami's Trac installer](https://bitnami.com/stack/trac), I still couldn't get my repository to be recognized by Trac. New repos set up through Trac seemed to work to some extent simply as blank repositories. The issue was I couldn't sync to them.

Specifically:

```
trac-admin [Trac folder]\[projects]\[project] repository resync (default)
TracError: Unsupported version control system "svn": cannot import name fs
```

I'm pretty sure the problem runs deeper, as that's an untouched SVN made by the Bitnami Trac Stack application. Additionally, as far as I know, this is the packaged version of Python it's using.

The log file says

```
2014-07-18 14:23:46,542 Trac[svn_fs] INFO: Failed to load Subversion bindings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-4vaacr\Trac-1.0-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\tracopt\versioncontrol\svn\svn_fs.py", line 273, in __init__
    _import_svn()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-4vaacr\Trac-1.0-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\tracopt\versioncontrol\svn\svn_fs.py", line 72, in _import_svn
    from svn import fs, repos, core, delta
ImportError: cannot import name fs
```

I am using Windows 7. Additionally, the repository set up by Trac can't be opened in TortoiseSVN Repository Browser:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///E:/Bitnami/Trac/default'
Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
Unable to open repository 'file:///E:/Bitnami/Trac/default'
Expected FS format between '1' and '4'; found format '6'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, it was an issue where Trac was trying to call the version of Python I installed for personal use, but installed things for its own copy, so I uninstalled it all, reinstalled it without a personal copy of Python, and ran it again. This time I got that various libraries weren't installed, which I could have sworn Bitnami took care of before.

All that it took to fix this was:

```
easy_install Trac==1.0
```

Setuptools, amd thus `easy_install`, is installed with Bitnami, so this isn't an issue. Afterwards I could sync the repository normally.